# nltk data fails to install on Ubuntu 14.04 of AWS instance type c4.xlarge

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, installation, nltk

I test installations script in Ubuntu 14.04 instance of AWS. Instance type c4.xlarge, using EBS 50 GB.
Every time installing, I start testing from a new instance I create.

Constantly the nltk Data fails to install on panlex_lite package.

Any ideas ? (I attached a lot of lines from the installation to identify with the information I see. Sorry for the long lists).

Thanks,

The commands I do before the nltk data are:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools -y
sudo apt-get install python3.4-dev -y

# Installing Python packages
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo easy_install3 inflect
sudo easy_install3 elasticsearch
sudo easy_install3 geopy
sudo easy_install3 geojson
sudo easy_install3 simplejson
sudo easy_install3 python_instagram
sudo easy_install3 flickrapi
sudo easy_install3 oauth
sudo easy_install3 xlrd
sudo easy_install3 pytz
sudo easy_install3 tweepy
sudo easy_install3 BeautifulSoup4
sudo easy_install3 psutil
sudo pip3 install -U nltk
sudo pip3 install -U numpy
sudo python3 -m nltk.downloader all
```

Last line fails. Log is the following starting from the finish of psutil:

```
Finished processing dependencies for psutil
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-30-0-207
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.1.tar.gz (1.1MB)
Installing collected packages: nltk
  Running setup.py install for nltk
Successfully installed nltk-3.1
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-30-0-207
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/ubuntu/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz (4.0MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.10.1
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-30-0-207
[nltk_data] Downloading collection 'all'
[nltk_data]    | 
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package abc to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/abc.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package alpino to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/alpino.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package biocreative_ppi to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/biocreative_ppi.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package brown to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/brown.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package brown_tei to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/brown_tei.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package cess_cat to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/cess_cat.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package cess_esp to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/cess_esp.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package chat80 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/chat80.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package city_database to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/city_database.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package cmudict to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/cmudict.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package comparative_sentences to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/comparative_sentences.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package comtrans to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package conll2000 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/conll2000.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package conll2002 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/conll2002.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package conll2007 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package crubadan to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/crubadan.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package dependency_treebank to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/dependency_treebank.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package europarl_raw to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/europarl_raw.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package floresta to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/floresta.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package framenet_v15 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/framenet_v15.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package gazetteers to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/gazetteers.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package genesis to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/genesis.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package gutenberg to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/gutenberg.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package ieer to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/ieer.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package inaugural to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/inaugural.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package indian to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/indian.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package jeita to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package kimmo to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/kimmo.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package knbc to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package lin_thesaurus to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/lin_thesaurus.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package mac_morpho to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/mac_morpho.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package machado to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package masc_tagged to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package moses_sample to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping models/moses_sample.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package movie_reviews to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/movie_reviews.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package names to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/names.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package nombank.1.0 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package nps_chat to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/nps_chat.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package oanc_masc to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package omw to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/omw.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package opinion_lexicon to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/opinion_lexicon.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package paradigms to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/paradigms.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package pil to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/pil.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package pl196x to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/pl196x.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package ppattach to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/ppattach.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package problem_reports to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/problem_reports.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package propbank to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package ptb to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/ptb.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package oanc_masc to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Package oanc_masc is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package product_reviews_1 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/product_reviews_1.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package product_reviews_2 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/product_reviews_2.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package pros_cons to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/pros_cons.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package qc to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/qc.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package reuters to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package rte to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/rte.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package semcor to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package senseval to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/senseval.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package sentiwordnet to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/sentiwordnet.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package sentence_polarity to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/sentence_polarity.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package shakespeare to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/shakespeare.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package sinica_treebank to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/sinica_treebank.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package smultron to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/smultron.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package state_union to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/state_union.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package stopwords to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/stopwords.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package subjectivity to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/subjectivity.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package swadesh to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/swadesh.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package switchboard to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/switchboard.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package timit to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/timit.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package toolbox to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/toolbox.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package treebank to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/treebank.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package twitter_samples to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/twitter_samples.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package udhr to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/udhr.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package udhr2 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/udhr2.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package unicode_samples to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/unicode_samples.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package universal_treebanks_v20 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package verbnet to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/verbnet.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package webtext to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/webtext.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package wordnet to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/wordnet.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package wordnet_ic to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/wordnet_ic.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package words to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/words.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package ycoe to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/ycoe.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package rslp to /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping stemmers/rslp.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package hmm_treebank_pos_tagger to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping taggers/hmm_treebank_pos_tagger.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package maxent_treebank_pos_tagger to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package universal_tagset to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping taggers/universal_tagset.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package maxent_ne_chunker to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping chunkers/maxent_ne_chunker.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package book_grammars to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping grammars/book_grammars.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package sample_grammars to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping grammars/sample_grammars.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package spanish_grammars to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping grammars/spanish_grammars.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package basque_grammars to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping grammars/basque_grammars.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package large_grammars to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping grammars/large_grammars.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package tagsets to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping help/tagsets.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package snowball_data to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package bllip_wsj_no_aux to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping models/bllip_wsj_no_aux.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package word2vec_sample to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping models/word2vec_sample.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package panlex_swadesh to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package mte_teip5 to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/mte_teip5.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger.zip.
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package panlex_lite to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/panlex_lite.zip.

Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
```

Also it is not size exception:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      51466360 6582776  42687092  14% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             3824796       8   3824788   1% /dev
tmpfs             765952     360    765592   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3829752       0   3829752   0% /run/shm
none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
```

Comment: See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1283#issuecomment-188251568

Answer (score 9):

I came across the same issue when using an old [AWS tutorial](http://blog.intelligencecomputing.io/analytics-bi/13436/repost-analyzing-big-data-getting-started-sentiment-analysis) for sentiment analysis of tweet data. 
This tutorial uses a bootstrap script to install NLTK and its data with command on a EMR cluster,

```
$ sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all
```

On running this command I get the exact same issue of *panlex_lite* installation. Since this is a bootstrap script, the prompt

> Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]

causes the bootstrap action to fail and EMR cluster gets terminated. :P

I have overcome this by:
A) assuming this package to be non essential
B) modifying the command to, pass a 'n' automatically so the script does not wait indefinitely.

```
$ yes n | sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all
```

Hope this helps.

Update 25Jan2016:
The data set named 'panlex_lite' still causes installation to fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps. I will do it.

Comment: Update: The EMR cluster bootstrap action still fails even after,
`$yes n | sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data all`
I figured out that the only package required form NLTK DATA is _punkt_
hence I edited the NLTK command to install it only.
`$ sudo python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/share/nltk_data punkt`

Comment: Updated for 20.1.16 - still fails. I will write to nltk_dala to view this post.

Comment: hello,
does it fail for a specific package ?
What does the error msg say ?

Comment: I saw only "Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]". I couldn't relize where the logs are. I looked at /var/log but didn't see any. the command I run is: sudo python3 -m nltk.downloader all.

Comment: Can please describe your OS, NLTK version and other information required to replicate your error ?

Comment: Ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server. instance of AWS. Instance type c4.xlarge, using EBS 50 GB. the NLTK data I install through sudo python3 -m nltk.downloader all.  nltk.__path__: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk']  nltk.__version__
'3.1'. Thanks

Comment: Hello,
I launched an instance with the specification you gave. Then installed pip3, nltk.
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install -U nltk
Then nltk_data with,
$ sudo python3 -m nltk.downloader all
this command gets stuck at :
"downloading package panlex_lite to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]    |   Unzipping corpora/panlex_lite.zip.

Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
y
[nltk_data]    | Downloading package panlex_lite to
[nltk_data]    |     /home/ubuntu/nltk_data..."
So i would assume the issue i due to this package.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I assume also. I wrote the issue to NLTK Data and hope they will fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure my experience.

In [**here**](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/59), a [**link**](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/blob/gh-pages/packages/corpora/panlex_lite.xml) is given for corpora/panlex and a link to file is given.  I download it.  It is a large file 1.7G before unzip.  The unziped file is put in `C:\nltk_data\corpora`. I am not sure how it works.  Hope it helpful.

Comment: I don't agree with you. This is a solution that helps by manually download the required file.

Comment: Thanks. I am searching for an automatic solution to download all packages.

Comment: Thank you! This helped resolve the issue with my installation.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [github issues](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1253), you might want to update your version of NLTK to the development version.

Also this specific file is really big, according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nltk-dev/k-SpYu6FlkY), it is around 1.7GB. So please be patient.