# Fail to download the nltk corpus in a virtual environment in the mac os x 10.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I tried to install the nltk corpus (actually what I need temporarily is `vader.text`) but I got such an error:

```
Error downloading 'panlex_lite' from
[nltk_data]    |     <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data
[nltk_data]    |     /gh-pages/packages/corpora/panlex_lite.zip>:
[nltk_data]    |     HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I tried both nltk installer and command line way. Why does this happen and how can I solve this? Thanks.

EDIT: I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182402/nltk-data-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-14-04-of-aws-instance-type-c4-xlarge) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nltk data fails to install on Ubuntu 14.04 of AWS instance type c4.xlarge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182402/nltk-data-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-14-04-of-aws-instance-type-c4-xlarge)

Comment: Please check if this solutions works for you, it is exactly the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182402/nltk-data-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-14-04-of-aws-instance-type-c4-xlarge

Comment: @SergioGarcia Thanks for your reply, but I still can not get this work. When I tried to run `sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()` I still got `No such file or directory: '/Users/yobichi/mc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/sentiment/vader_lexicon.txt'`. I typed `yes n | sudo python -m nltk.downloader all` in the command(virtualenv). Could you help me with this? My python version is 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue & would like to share how I resolved it:

Step 1) When downloading vader_lexicon by `nltk.download()` which opens the NLTK Downloader, the file is downloaded as a zip. Seeing that the error message says that the .txt file is not available, I decided to unzip the file.

Step 2) I compared the file location to the pathway indicated by the error message. 
 - My `vader_lexicon.txt` file was in `.../nltk_data/sentiment/vader_lexicon/vader_lexicon.txt`. 
 - Whereas apparently it was needed at `.../lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/sentime‌​nt/vader_lexicon.txt‌​`.

Instead of configuring paths, I went with "brute force" and decided to move the .txt file to the right place. Problem solved.

(Python 2.7, nltk 3.1, Mac)